# How can I centralize dependecny version when using `nx` in a monorepo with `yarn4 png`?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a typescript monorepo managed by `nx`. There are about 122 projects in this repo and all written in `typescript` nodejs. With `yarn4 pnp` enabled `https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp`.

There are some 3rd party dependencies used by most of the projects in this monorepo. I am looking for a way to let all projects share the same version of shared dependecnies and found `nx` has a suggestion that put those dependencies in root level of package.json: https://nx.dev/concepts/more-concepts/dependency-management.

However, it is not working with `yarn4 pnp` which requries all dependencies used by the projects need to be listed in project level `package.json`.

So what is the right way to enforce same dependencies' versions while keep using `yarn pnp`?